# sql count the number of times two values share the same value from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table:

```
ID  State
---------
0   A   
1   A   
2   C   
3   C   
2   A      
3   A    
2   D      
0   D    
2   E      
3   F
```

and here is the result:

```
ID1 ID2 N_State
---------
0   1   1
2   3   2
2   0   1
```

the question is:
**to count the number of states that two IDs have in common and output as the above format?**

Comment: (1) These is not the full result set (2) 0 and 2 are connected by both A and D

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz yes i forgot it in the results!thanks your answer is perfect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select      t1.id,t2.id,count(*) as N_State

from                mytable t1
            join    mytable t2
            on      t2.State = t1.State
                and t2.id > t1.id 

group by    t1.id,t2.id
```

---

```
+----+----+----------+
| id | id | count(*) |
+----+----+----------+
| 0  | 1  | 1        |
+----+----+----------+
| 0  | 2  | 2        |
+----+----+----------+
| 0  | 3  | 1        |
+----+----+----------+
| 1  | 2  | 1        |
+----+----+----------+
| 1  | 3  | 1        |
+----+----+----------+
| 2  | 3  | 2        |
+----+----+----------+
```

---

Adding row number

```
select      @i:=@i+1 as i
           ,id1,id2,N_State

from        (select      t1.id as id1,t2.id as id2,count(*) as N_State

             from                mytable t1

                         join    mytable t2

                         on      t2.State = t1.State
                             and t2.id > t1.id 

             group by    t1.id,t2.id
             ) t

             cross join (select @i:=-1) x

order by    id1,id2
```

Comment: how can i add a column as the first column of the results table, which just holds the row number independant of the main table, starting from 0 and auto-increments on each row?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: i am using sql in phpmyadmin

Comment: thanks, but i get an error on the cross join line? why is that? and could you please rename the column to "Number"?

Comment: Not sure, try again (I added an alias to the row number)

Comment: actually i am adding a where statement after `group by`, to check if both t1.id and t2.id both exist in the list, i did like this, but i am not sure if it is correct: `WHERE (t1.id1 AND t2.id2) IN (mylist)`

Comment: put `WHERE (t1.id,t2.id) IN (mylist)` inside the sub-query (between the FROM and the GROUP BY). `IN (mylist)` should look something like `IN ((1,2),(3,4),(1,3))` (t2.id > t1.id)

Comment: no, my list is like (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), I want to check if both `t1.id,t2.id` exist in the same list. I can do `WHERE t1.id IN (mylist) AND t2.id IN (mylist)` 
but is it possible to do something like `WHERE (t1.id1 AND t2.id2) IN (mylist)` ? because it is way shorter.

Comment: No, you'll need 2 checks